# Ubuntu 16.04/17.10 does not boot on Dell e5570

Tags: boot, usb, kernel, dell

I run Ubuntu on a 32GB USB3.0 stick. (I use shared computers, and don't wish to touch the computer's hard-drive)

I have been using Ubuntu 17.04 with kernel 4.10 on a Dell e5570 since it came out.

When I install Ubuntu 16.04 or 17.10 onto the USB stick (as 17.04 stopped receiving updates), and run it on the Dell e5570, it failed to boot. Each time it fails in a different way.

1. It makes it to the login screen, I sign in, and it goes to black screen.
2. I make it to the login screen, and as I move the cursor, it goes to black screen.
3. It hangs on the Ubuntu logo
4. While booting, it give an EXT4 error
5. While booting, its gives a kernel panic error

I thought it was the USB stick I was installing Ubuntu on, or the usb starter disk, but different sticks have the same result.

Also, I don't think its a hard-drive error since the same USB installed Ubuntu that fails on an e5770 loads fine on a Dell E5440 (I'm using this now).

The only thing I can think of is that the linux kernel after 4.10 is not compatible with the Dell E5570. This is of some concern, as this is the main shared computer some universities have adopted. There are thousands of this model at my university (upgraded from the previous E5440), and hence anyone who wants to use Ubuntu on these machines is not going to be able to.

Has anyone heard anything about this, and is there a workaround for it ?

Comment: 4.10 is from 17.04 so if that was running fine for you, it's likely not the issue. 17.10 has 4.13, and if you install all the updates for 16.04, you should also have 4.13 at this point. There could also be an issue with the USB hardware in that machine, which recently developed. It's going to be quite difficult for anyone here to give you a helpful answer though, as there could be so many things causing such a problem. Have you tried other USB ports on the machine?

Comment: Ive now tried all USB ports, still the same problem.  I also tried changing the RAID to ACHI seetting in the BIOS with no improvement. The only logical reason I can think of is that the newer kernel (4.13) is not compatible with the E5570. I might try 16.04 with earlier kernel versions. But this means that I will never be able to update my OS

Comment: I highly doubt it is the kernel version. If as you say, 17.04 was working fine, it is almost certainly not the kernel version. It is far more likely the flash on the USB is failing, or the USB controller on the machine in question, is failing. Have you tried a different USB drive? An actual SSD rather than a flash drive perhaps?